# passing word in a command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, arguments

I am actually new in shell scripting. I have a file.txt written 662,2016-12-31.

example: #cat file.txt

662,2016-12-31

I have another script.sh file with command 
'{print $2",0"$1",field1,field2}'

example: #cat script.sh

'{print $2",0"$1",field1,field2}'

I want to print 662 at field1 and 2016-12-31 in field2. Can it be done?

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question so it's more clear - that's the secret to getting a great answer on Stack Overflow. Right now I've no idea what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: To be honest, no. However, take a look at that: `cat file.txt | perl -ne 'print "field1: $1 field2: $2\n" if /(.*),(.*)/'`. You can now modify a part after `print` to reorder your fields, or add some characters in between. If that's what you need.

Comment: "cat install_offer1.csv | sed 's/"880//g' |sed 's/"88//g'| sed 's/"//g'|sed 's/,019/,19/g'| nawk -F, '{print $1",0"$2",field1,field2"}' > install_offer2.csv"   actually this is the full command. I just want to print 662 at the place of field1 and 2016-12-31 at the place of field2. so whenever i change the file.txt, the command will also change as it always takes the argument from the file.txt.

Comment: Do you want the output line look like `argument2,0argument1,662,2016-12-31` ? In that case you could do without `(n)awk`: `printf "%s,0%s,%s\n" "$2" "$1" "$(cat file.txt)"`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved using `awk` command. You can check following simple shell script,

```
#!/bin/sh

InputData=`cat file.txt`

field1=`echo $InputData | awk -F "," '{print $1}'`
field2=`echo $InputData | awk -F "," '{print $2}'`

echo "field1=$field1"
echo "field2=$field2"
```

Output:

```
field1=662
field2=2016-12-31
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get value of field1 and field2 by using `cut` command with delimiter as    **","**

```
field1=`cat file.txt | cut -d "," -f1`
field2=`cat file.txt | cut -d "," -f2`

'{print $2",0"$1",$field1,$field2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

> "…| nawk -F, '{print $1",0"$2",field1,field2"}' > install_offer2.csv" actually this is the full command. I just want to print 662 at the place of field1 and 2016-12-31 at the place of field2. so whenever i change the file.txt, the command will also change as it always takes the argument from the file.txt.

The easy part is to read the fields from the file into variables:

```
IFS=, read field1 field2 <file.txt
```

The not quite, but almost so easy part is to insert those variables' values into the `nawk` command, since as it stands within single quotes, no shell parameter expansion takes place. Following are two possible approaches.

1. Assign the shell variables to `awk` variables with the option `-v`:

   ```
   …|nawk -F, -v field1=$field1 -v field2=$field2 '{print $1",0"$2","field1","field2}'
   ```

   Note that `field1` and `field2` must appear outside of the `"` `"` strings.
2. Insert the shell variables directly by closing and reopening the `'` quote:

   ```
   …|nawk -F, '{print $1",0"$2",'$field1,$field2'"}'
   ```

If we look at the second way, another, even easier possibility comes to mind, which doesn't require the step to `read` variables:

```
…|nawk -F, '{print $1",0"$2",'$(<file.txt)'"}'
```